# Entity Framework Code-Based Migration - Visual Studio Lockup on Update -Script

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Using EF 4.3.1 code-based migrations.  I have added a new migration (after the initial) and done an update-database.  Now I want to generate a database script file so I run:

Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:$InitialDatabase

When I do that, Visual Studio locks up.  I see 2 new tabs: SqlQuery_1.sql and tmp5003.sql

Any idea what is causing this and how to get past it?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem. Do you have a connection open to the database somewhere else? Management studio, or the server explorer in visual studio?

Comment: I also have this problem but did not found any solution yet. I don't have any opened connection to the database. Any idea?